# HTTP Event Cloud Function: request body value is undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When sending `{"identifiant": "iJXB5E0PsoKq2XrU26q6"}` to the below Cloud Function, I cannot get the `identifiant` value in the request body and it will always return `PROBLEMAS NO REQUEST`.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.meusCandidatos = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const identifiant = req.body.identifiant;

    if(identifiant) res.status(200).json('ok').end();

    res.status(500).json('PROBLEMAS NO REQUEST').end();

});
```

Comment: I'm dealing with this issue too. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike a [Callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), the body of a request is not parsed automatically and needs to be parsed before you can use it.

In addition, `json(...)` will call `end()` internally so you don't need both. Also make sure that you don't call `end()`, `send()`, `json()`, etc. multiple times, as this will lead to errors.

```
const jsonParser = require('body-parser').json();

exports.meusCandidatos = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    jsonParser(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
        return; // stop here
      }

      const identifiant = req.body.identifiant;

      if (!identifiant) {
        res.status(500).json({error: 'PROBLEMAS NO REQUEST'});
        return; // stop here
      }

      // continue
      res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok' });
  })
});
```

Comment: How would you parse the request body in a typescript file? I've tried `console.log("JSON VALUE: " + JSON.parse(request.body.postId))` but that isn't working for me