# Request body values not being picked up in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Below I am trying to send a request to a firebase cloud function, & return a value from that request inside the response body.

Here is my firebase cloud function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const jsonParser = require('body-parser').json();

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export const updateLikesCount = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    jsonParser(request, response, () => {
        console.log(request.body.postId);
        response.status(200).json({ status: 'ok' });
    });
});
```

And here is the request body which I am POSTing to the URL:

```
{
    "postId": "bYS2PlClUj3MzRM3ZwcM",
    "userId": "f9itQBG67mYTz205ZpiryUtbcrM2",
    "action": "like"
}
```

But when I look at the firebase logs, postId is still being returned as undefined

Comment: Add a debug log with the value of `postId`.  Does it contain what you expect?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson I've stripped away the code & updated it above. As you can see, for some reason the postId isn't being picked up, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What is inside request.body in firebase? Can you log request.body and request.params and post the results?

Comment: I've updated the question with the request body & request params. I also tried to return userId & action in the response body, they're both also coming back as UNDEFINED

Comment: The request body is not automatically parsed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235019/http-event-cloud-function-request-body-value-is-undefined

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen I've looked at this question, & tried to do `console.log("JSON VALUE: " + JSON.parse(request.body.postId));` but I'm getting "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0" error

Comment: You need to parse the body, before you can use `request.body.id`. Did you use ` jsonParser(req, res, (err) => {` anywhere?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've updated my question above. I installed body-parser, but `undefined` is still appearing in the firebase logs

Comment: If you now `console.log(request.body, JSON.stringify(request.body))`, what does it show in Cloud Logging?