# Pass data from cloud task to a firebase cloud function - currently getting an error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

My question is this: how do I call a Firebase Cloud Function from a Cloud task and pass a payload through?

I tried following the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@rogiervandenberg/google-cloud-task-queues-on-gcp-with-google-cloud-functions-22eb80fe34ba). The only difference is that I'm using Cloud functions for Firebase instead of regular Cloud Functions.

Here is my cloud function.

```
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    
    exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      console.log(req.query);
      res.send('success');
    });
```

When I query the url in the browser with parameters `?myparams=data` I can log 'data' so I know the cloud function is basically working.

But when I try to call it from my queue (below) I get:

```
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

My guess is that req is undefined.

I've been looking at this SO question and I am wondering if it has something to do with needing to use bodyParser for onRequest functions.

[HTTP Event Cloud Function: request body value is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235019/http-event-cloud-function-request-body-value-is-undefined)

I'm also seeing that some people have [CORS issues](https://erikmartinjordan.com/undefined-post-request-firebase) with their cloud functions, which seems like it might be related.

Here is the task queue code that should be sending the payload.

```
        const seconds = 5;
        const project = 'xxxxx-xxxxxxx';
        const queue = 'xxxxx';
        const location = 'us-west2';
        const url = 'https://us-central1-xxxxx-xxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/writeDB';
        const payload = 'My data';
        const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);
    
        const task = {
          httpRequest: {
            httpMethod: "POST",
            url: url,
            body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString("base64"),
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            oidcToken: {
              serviceAccountEmail
            }
          }
        };
          
        task.scheduleTime = {
          seconds: seconds + Date.now() / 1000,
        };
  
        const request = {parent: parent, task: task};

        await client.createTask(request)
        .then(response => {
          const task = response[0].name;
          console.log(`Created task ${task}`);

          return {'Response': String(response)}
        
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.error(`Error in createTask: ${err.message || err}`);
          next()
      });
```

It calls the function, but for some reason it results in the error and the payload isn't logged.

Can anyone help?

As always, I'm happy to clarify the question if anything is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: "crashes/gives an error" -- what error? Please read [ask].

Comment: I think I've been getting some different errors trying different things - mostly its SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0. I think it's because maybe response.whatever is undefined.

Comment: I also get Error: could not handle the request in the browser.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Your payload seems to be string. May be try something like `payload = {"name":"Some Shit"}`

Comment: haha I forget that I had that wording in the string LOL

Comment: @Asdfg good idea, but no immediate help. res.query logs from the browser, but when I call it from the cloud task I still get `Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0`

Comment: try `console.log(req);`. that may give you what the req.body looks like.

Comment: @Asdfg -  tried that first thing, but it's giving me unexpected token error - no idea why.

Comment: and tried console.log(JSON.stringify(res)) and console.log(JSON.parse(res)) just for good measure.

Comment: You have 2 components: a Cloud Tasks creator that makes HTTP POST requests shipping JSON and a Cloud Function that should accept HTTP POST requests parsing JSON. I encourage you to disaggregate the two components and test them in isolation. You can use a tool like [`request.bin`](https://requestbin.com/) as a proxy for the Cloud Function, be the target for the Cloud Tasks and `request.bin` will log the method, body etc. for you. You can use `curl` to test the Cloud Function `curl --request POST --data '{"name": "Freddie"}' https://us-central1-spiral-48266.cloudfunctions.net/writeDB`.

Comment: Your question is haphazard and makes it slightly difficult to help. It also (evidently) makes debugging more painful. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request) suggests that (as you are) setting `Content-Type: application/json` automatically (!) unmarshals the body and so you need not `JSON.parse` (again). Please update the question with @asdfg (correct) suggestion to use JSON for the payload.  Why is `const { seconds } = req.body`? That makes no sense. Please simplify the question. It doesn't help us help you as is.

Comment: @DazWilkin - apologize, you're right I tried to put too much into one question. That second part is good to know about  `Content-Type: application/json' so i don't need it again.

Comment: `const { seconds } = req.body ` was because I omitted a surrounding express endpoint. I updated the question, it's just seconds = 5.

Comment: Basically the error `Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0` tells you that you're trying to parse an object which is already in parsed form.

Comment: I'm getting it even when I'm not trying to parse anything..

Comment: Can you try to modify the format of your `payload` initialization? Use `json` format for your payload instead of just enclosing it as string the same way it was initialized in the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@rogiervandenberg/google-cloud-task-queues-on-gcp-with-google-cloud-functions-22eb80fe34ba).

Comment: If you want to retain const `payload = 'My data';` modify your content type to `"Content-Type": "text/plain"`

Comment: @CatherineO thank you, that was part of the problem and it was creating the error that was throwing me off. In addition to that I found out that including the service account email was creating `Error in createTask: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.` that I had been missing because it didn't stop the server restarting. Not sure why I don't need to include my service account email and can still call the function? Anyway I'm back on track... I'll probably try to answer this myself when I figure out why I didn't need the service account email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your error and I managed to fix it by changing the **content type** **headers** from `"application/json"` to `"text/plain"`. I have also removed the `JSON.stringify()` function in the **body** value because your payload variable is a **String** type. Below is my modified sample of your code:

```js
const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');

// Instantiates a client.
const client = new CloudTasksClient();

const seconds = 5;
const serviceAccountEmail = "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com";
const project = 'xxxx-xxxxxx';
const queue = "xx-xxxxx";
const location = 'us-central1';
const url = "https://us-central1-xxxxx-xxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction";

const payload = 'My Data';

const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);

async function quickstart() {

    const task = {
        httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: "POST",
        url: url,
        body: Buffer.from(payload).toString("base64"), // your previous code: body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString("base64"),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        },
        oidcToken: {
            serviceAccountEmail
        }
        }
    };
        
    task.scheduleTime = {
        seconds: seconds + Date.now() / 1000,
    };

    const request = {parent: parent, task: task};

    await client.createTask(request)
    .then(response => {
        const task = response[0].name;
        console.log(`Created task ${task}`);
        return {'Response': String(response)}

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`Error in createTask: ${err.message || err}`);
        next()
    });

}
quickstart();
```

In **Cloud Functions**, I changed `req.query` to `req.body` to get the result from **Cloud Tasks**

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log('success')
    res.send('success');
  });
```

Comment: thanks, so simple but this and another problem with my oidcToken was causing my headache.

Comment: I suggest you post another question regarding oidcToken for you to better track your raised concerns.